# service workers in salesforce

Tags: lightning, mobile, file-storage, offline

Hey I am building a salesforce lightning application to present html slide shows with images and videos.

I would like to store the assets on the device so that the presentation can still be shown when the agent is offline.

My question is? Does salesforce SDK expose the device filesystem?

Alternatively is there a way to achieve persistent caching of files through a service-worker within a salesforce lightning application?

Comment: Salesforce Mobile SDK which supports offline capability.Please look into below resources https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/mobile_sdk_offline

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pAq6UEDlBDQ

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/offline_management.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're building with the Salesforce Mobile SDK (either native or hybrid with the Cordova flavour of the plugin) you'll have access to the filesystem

You'll also be able to use Service Workers if you're building out a hybrid app.

Both your routes should be available to you.